# Way to refer to the "act" of praising a person/inflating their ego with the intention of later causing their downfall?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word/words/phrase that describes putting someone on a high pedestal only to bring him down later. Any word that follows this chain of activity may also do, "*act of false praise-act of bringing down (the other person)*".

> Jack ________ the other person.

*Flattery* will not work here, as it means to praise to gain something.

*Bullshitted* will not work either, as the other person might be aware that he is being bullshitted. Also bullshitting may not be in the form of praise or flattery, may be simply in the nature of giving some vague answer.

*Deceive* will not work either, as deception can also be done without praise.

---

**Edit 1:** [Leading someone on](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leading+on) generally means to encourage someone's romantic or sexual interest without sincerity. This **insincerity** in the first phase with the **intention of (at future or opportune time) humiliation/destruction/bringing down** after putting on a die/pedestal/high place or "*puncturing the ego balloon after causing an inflated ego*", is what I am looking for in the "word/words/phrase".

It is not plain deception. Also motive for deception is self-benefit. In this word the *primary* motive is the downfall of the other person.

Basically a word/words/phrase for "*entrapment*" to cause "*later downfall*" (of the other person).

---

**Edit 2:** "Fattening up" is coming close to the meaning of what I am searching but in animal form, as in "fattening up the animal for slaughter". Are there similar words (verbs or verbifiable words or loan words) in English or Germanic or Slavic languages or Hebrew language with similar meaning but in the human world?

---

**Edit 3:** If only “jacked and dropped” or “puffed and punctured” were phrases or idioms. Similarly, if these were real words “cliffsided”, “mountaintopped”, “hilltopped” (with the intention of shoving); “head-aired”, “ego-ballooned”, “vacuoused”, “bird-brained”, “fatuoused” (with the intention of humiliating later), they'd be useful too.

Comment: False praise. The person doing the FALSE praising is going to destroy the person he is praising now when the time is ripe. Imagine a situation where the person is setting this other person up for a major upset, humiliation, defeat, but by inflating this other person's ego first.

Comment: What specific scenario are you describing? What are the motives behind the people doing the building and destroying?

Comment: Praise first, inflate the ego, destroy. Motives can be anything. Humiliation can be a motive.

Comment: Being *Sandbagged* doesn't put the mark on a pedestal by overstating his/her abilities, but instead understates those of the hustler to lower her/his standing in the eyes of the mark. Although it doesn't match your scenario, it does use the same strategy by creating the same artificial/false feeling of superiority in the mark and raises his/her confidence until blindsided by the hustler.

Comment: Take this as a link-only answer which I'll try to convert into a real answer next week when I'm back from holidays: https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/plamas/.

Comment: Make a movie with a one-word title in which this happens and we'll all start using it.  Worked with "catfish"!

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's necessarily helpful to ask for ***a single word*** covering such situations, but *in context* OP might be understood if he used the "nounified" version of a "verbified" derivative ([***strawmanning***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22strawmanning%22)) to mean "the act of creating a straw man".

> [**straw man**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/straw_man)
> An intentionally misrepresented proposition that is set up because it is easier to defeat than an opponent's real argument.

Comment: Strawmanning is good. It does not however convey what I have in mind. Imagine a clever person setting up a trap by puffing up the ego of a foolish person with  false praise. When the time is ripe the trap will be shut and this other person will be humiliated.

Comment: I can imagine the scenario you propose, and I'm perfectly happy to defend "strawmanning" as describing what that clever person is doing. Sure, it could more accurately be called ***preparatory** strawmanning* (because the "sting" comes *later*). But you could say that about lots of nefarious activities with an intended later "payoff". Paedophile ***grooming***, for example.

Comment: ...I'm guessing you didn't look at any of the example usages of ***strawmanning*** as linked to in my answer. There are actually quite a lot of them, and I really do think they're mostly using the word with the sense you seek.

Comment: I do agree with you and I had seen the examples. Strawmanning is only lacking in the "praise first" part

Answer (score 2):

I understand that your context is along the lines of *sabotaging* (and other words with the meaning "defeating/bringing down someone by indirect means", like *undermine*) but I don't believe there is a single word that condenses all the actions, *praise-deceive-bring down*, into a single word.

There are some words that can be considered with a context around them. For example, ***honeyfuggle*** (also *honeyfackle, honeyfugle, honeyfogle*) is a US slang/dialectal word that can cover praising and deceiving; however you need to include bringing down in the context. It also has stronger negative connotations than, say, *flatter* or *cajole*; where they are more about persuading or enticing by flattering words. Here is the *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88174#eid1527887)* definition of *honeyfuggle* and a relevant example:

> *U.S. colloquial.* Now somewhat dated. 
> **1.** 
> **a.** *transitive.* To deceive, swindle; to cajole. 
> **b.** transitive. To obtain by duplicity or blandishment. *rare.* 
> **2.** *intransitive.* To act in an underhand, indirect, or ingratiating manner in order to deceive a person or to obtain something. Also with around.
>
> The modern practices in politics..of honey-fuggling with rascals instead of hitting them a death blow between the eyes. 
> <sub>1887   Courier-Jrnl. (Louisville, Kentucky) 7 May 4</sub>

*Knife* is another US slang verb with the connotation of defeating someone by underhanded means; used in political context mainly. Here is the *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/104010?rskey=5owuja&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)* definition and a relevant example:

> *U.S. slang.* To strike at secretly; to endeavour to defeat in an underhand way.
>
> He speaks favourably of them in a leading article, and ‘knifes’ them slyly in paragraphs. 
> <sub>1888   Nation (N.Y.) 5 July 3/1</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The phrasal verb *set up* works.

> *Jack set up the other person.*

Follow the *OED* scroll . . .

> **set,** *v.<sup>1</sup>*
> **Phrasal verbs**
> **PV2.** With adverbs in specialized senses.
> **to set up**
> **III.** To put in operation, establish.
> **29.**
> **c.** To bring (someone) to a position from which he may be knocked down, to make vulnerable (*literal*, as in *Pugilism*); *figurative*
> (*colloquial* and *slang*), to lead on in order to fool, cheat, or
> incriminate (a person); to ‘frame’. Originally U.S.
>  <sub>Source:
> [The Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Selected samples from the entry . . .

> <sub>1950   J. DEMPSEY *Championship Fighting* x. 49    If
> you can land solidly with a straight left or with a left hook, you'll
> generally knock your opponent off balance, at least, and ‘set him up’
> for a pot-shot with your right.</sub>
>
> <sub>1964    S. BELLOW *Herzog* 109    Of course he
> understood that Tennie was setting him up, and that he was a sucker
> for just the sort of appeal she made.</sub>
>
> <sub>1981    ‘E. V. CUNNINGHAM’ *Case of Sliding Pool* ix. 101
>   He had a partner, whom he set up from the very beginning for
> the kill.</sub>

As a phrasal verb, it should be split if you use a pronoun: *Jack set her up.*

You can also use it as a noun: *Jack's actions amounted to a set-up.*

Comment: I want a word/words/phrase which conveys both the action of setting up the person and the later action of humiliation/destruction/bringing down. e.g. setting up for humiliation almost makes it. But I want it to sound classy or almost idiomatic. In Hindi language in India, there is a saying "flying the kite and cutting the string", but it's too long. In the OP,  I gave an example of "fattening up for slaughter", however it sounds too bad. Also a person can set himself up for a promotion. I want this word to mean doing harm only to the other person (this person is unaware that he is played)

Comment: A set-up has an unaware victim, a means, and a motive. Fatten up a calf so you can eat it. Fake a left punch so you can knock someone out with a right. Set out a pile of money so you can nab a thief. You haven't said how you intend flattery to work, but maybe: Flatter someone so they allow you close enough to find the flaws that you will use against them...

Comment: ...A set-up also carries with it an outcome... The calf was set up: and we ate for dinner / but it ran away before we could eat it / but we ate the lamb instead. Are you instead looking for an idiom for that suggests the act of setting up? (*Setting oneself up for promotion* uses a different definition of *set-up*.)

Answer (score 1):

*Jack overinflated the other person*
might be interpreted as
*Jack overinflated the ego of the other person*

Someone whose ego is overinflated is at risk of being brought down by reality and circumstance.

For example:

> [Resurfacegroup](https://www.resurfacegroup.com/post/inflated-ego-in-recovery)
> People with overinflated egos struggle to acknowledge flaws or vulnerabilities- both to themselves and to other people. As a result, they tend to deny problematic behaviors. They feel uncomfortable asking for peer support or connecting with others.

This usage is an extension of the more prosaic idea of overinflation that may apply - for example - to tyres or balloons, both of which are set up to fail by being overinflated.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overinflate)
> overinflate, transitive verb
> to inflate (something) too much
> *overinflate a car's tires*
> Other Words from overinflate:
> overinflated, adjective
> *overinflated prices*
> *an overinflated ego*

Hence, to overinflate someone’s ego is hardly done accidentally (as might happen with inflating tyres); if done at all, it is done with intent. And what is the likely intent? It is not a benevolent intent: it is to set someone up to be brought down.

Comment: Yes, "overinflated" is very good and nearly conveys what I am searching for. Thank you. Is/are there even better words meaning the same thing?

Comment: I don't think "overinflated" is at all useful for OP's context, because it very strongly implies that the person who's doing the unjustified "bigging up" is ***mistaken*** in their attitude towards the subject (not that they're ***deliberately*** bigging up the subject so they can engineer a more spectacular fall from grace later).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think overinflation may be accidental or intentional. It merely refers to the act, and may be either. However, your comment is a welcome reminder to add a definition to my answer.

Comment: I don't claim "overinflate" *can't* be used in OP's context - simply that *as a single word* it doesn't really work. Sure, you could say that the popular press often "overinflate" someone newly in the public eye - but unless you explicitly include mention of ***in order to tear them down later***, I doubt any reasonable audience would actually *assume* such a cynical unstated implication.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I found your comment stimulating and have tried to explain better. Thanks.

Comment: These are matters of opinion, I'm sure. But in my example "popular press"  scenario, I think it's a bit extreme to characterise the initial "bigging up" as "not a benevolent intent". It's the same as early movie reviews often being far more enthusiastic than appears subsequently justified. Those early glowing reviews might be partly affected by critics sucking up to the movie industry so they'll continue to receive freebie Blu-Ray "review copies", but mostly it's just that ***new = interesting = good*** (until you watch it again and realise it's crap! :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider *con:*

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/con) [Definition 2]:

> ***con***
>
> [verb (used with object), conned, con·ning]
>
> - to swindle; trick:
>   *That crook conned me out of all my savings.*
> - to persuade by deception, cajolery, etc.:
>   *Don't worry, I can always con my dad into letting me use his car.*
>
> ---
>
> [noun]
>
> - a confidence game or swindle:
>   *By the time my uncle realized she was playing a con on him, she had already left town with his rare coin collection.*
> - a lie, exaggeration, or glib self-serving talk:
>   *He had a dozen different cons for getting out of paying traffic tickets.*
>
> ---
>
> [adjective]
>
> - relating to or involving abuse of confidence:
>   *a slick con man;*
>   *a con trick.*

As a note, the part of the con that involves the gaining of confidence from the target is usually referred to as the "***setup***" or "***set up***", so in the original example, it could be said "John [set up, was setting up] the other person."

Answer (score 1):

‘Sandbagged’ is the most appropriate word that I can find.

Asking an Alexa smart speaker the following:

> Alexa, give me more definitions for sandbag

Results in this response:

> ‘I have 10 more definitions for sandbag: As a noun, 1. such a bag used as a weapon. As a verb, 2. to hit or stun with a sandbag. 3. to set upon violently; attack from or **as if from ambush**. 4. to coerce or intimidate, as by threats. 5. **to thwart or cause to fail** or be rejected, especially surreptitiously or without warning. 6. **to deceive (one or more opponents) into remaining in the pot by refraining from betting on a strong hand, then raising the bet in a later round**. 7. **to gain an advantage over** (one or more competitors) **by concealing one's abilities or other strengths early in** a game or other **competitive activity**. 8. **to gain an advantage by concealing or downplaying the strengths of (something)**. 9. to sandbag one or more opponents. 10. to sandbag an opponent or competitor.’

**Source:** Amazon Alexa

Answer (score 1):

Some answers here seem to be recommending  all sorts of unseemly words. I should use **entrap**. *Jack entrapped the other person with fulsome words*. Depending on the context you may not need to specify why that is entrapment. If you ettle to show the “downfall” of this other person, or the effect of Jacks words on him  at a later point, then you need not specify why it is entrapment.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a single word for the "act" of praising a person with the intention of bringing down this person later?

No.

The classic reference here is [Mark Anthony's speech in Shakespeare's Julius Caesar Act III, Scene 2](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=juliuscaesar&Act=3&Scene=2&Scope=scene) and the repetition of "Brutus is an honourable man" is heavy with irony.

> Here, under leave of Brutus and the rest– /
> (For Brutus is an honourable man; /
> So are they all, all honourable men) /
> Come I to speak in Caesar’s funeral. /
> He was my friend, faithful and just to me: /
> But Brutus says he was ambitious; /
> And Brutus is an honourable man.

The "Jack __ the other person." has to be expressed by a descriptive construction that probably will have some reference to "heavy irony".

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that the simple answer to the question is "No:  there is no such word.". Many of the answers given get as near to a single-word answer, in some case resorting to more than one word, in other cases using a single word that is about as near as a single word can possibly get.

The ancient Greeks shared a saying that the Gods raise up those that they intend to cast down.  The essence of tragegy was the cycle of success ('koros'), giving rise to overconfidence/arrogance ('hybris'), leading to a disastrous mistake ('nemesis').  But there is no single word that does the job being looked for here.  There are words for elements of the process of tricking someone into disaster: 'lure', for example or 'inveigle', but neither of these contain the notion of flattery and disaster, or not specifically.

So I am afraid that while it is possible to construct a phrase that could do the job, I do not think there is a single word.

Answer (score -2):

In a word, failure.

Also "horror business."

Comment: I can't see how either suggestion can been taken as the "act" of praising a person with the intention of bringing down this person later.

Comment: I can't think of a single word that would set up this entire premise, but lacking self-awareness and overly obsessed come to mind. I'm going to have to check a thesaurus and some movies, maybe listen to some music and think on this.  You keep plotting, and don't look away, so when the target isn't paying attention to you at all, you can get your gotcha