# Is there a word for doing something you normally wouldn't do just to prove a point/make a statement?

Tags: single-word-requests

As title says, is there a word for doing something you normally wouldn't do just to prove a point/make a statement?

**For Example:** *I am at work, and there is a rule that allows certain behavior; so I take said behavior to the most extreme just to show how ridiculous the rule is.*

Is there a word for such an action? I could've swore there was, but cannot find anything describing what I am looking for on Google.

Comment: "doing something stupid to prove a point" ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1llq4q/what_is_something_stupid_youve_done_to_prove_a/)) or similar ([Cracked](https://www.cracked.com/article_16760_6-people-who-died-in-order-to-prove-retarded-point.html)). This seems the usual phrase in everyday (US) English. There may be a more obscure alternative though.

Comment: Please tell the obscure alternative, it may answer my question https://english.stackexchange.com/q/593582/397404. I am still looking for an answer to that question.

Comment: doing something "out of spite" matches the title of the question, but maybe not the example given.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular sentence you've given, the term **malicious compliance** might be appropriate. [As Wikipedia says:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance)

> Malicious compliance (also known as malicious obedience) is the behavior of strictly following the orders of a superior despite knowing that compliance with the orders will have an unintended or negative result. The term usually implies following an order in such a way that ignores or otherwise undermines the order's intent, but follows it to the letter.

Comment: malicious compliance is more about doing what a rule says you should do, rather than doing something a rule says you may do.

Answer (score 1):

I have been on and off in search of this very word for years and, unfortunately, haven't found it yet.

Malicious compliance would exclusively describe your willingness to comply with something that is wrong.

Reductio ad absurdum would describe your doing so in such an extreme manner
as to point out the absurdity of the action being taken if it were to reach its ultimate conclusion.

But nothing was found to describe what you were actually asking for.

Until it is found, I have coined my own, namely: "hypokriatropoapseudal"

- adjective describing the unnatural (atypical) behaviour of oneself to make another face a situation so they don't get to curate their reaction to it or lie about what their actions would be if explored merely in the hypothetical.

Example: (formal)-  To make him face the reality of the situation, I had to take a hypokriatropoapseudal approach.

(informal)- I went hypokriatropoapseudal on his ass; I had no other choice.

From ὑπόκρισις Ἄτροπος Ἀψευδὴ - hypokrisis atropos apseudes

ὑπόκρισις= from ῠ̔ποκρῑ́νομαι (hupokrī́nomai, “I answer (a fellow actor on stage), play a part, feign, pretend”)+‎ -σῐς (-sis).

I chose this to describe the fact that you are acting, pretending (you are not being your genuine self).

Ἄτροπος= (/ˈætrəpɒs, -pəs/;[1][2] Ancient Greek: Ἄτροπος "without turn") or Aisa,
in Greek mythology, was one of the three Moirai, goddesses of fate and destiny. Her Roman equivalent was Morta.

Atropos was the oldest of the Three Fates, and was known as "the Inflexible One."[3]
It was Atropos who chose the manner of death and ended the life of mortals by cutting their threads.[4]
She worked along with her two sisters, Clotho, who spun the thread, and Lachesis, who measured the length.

I chose this to describe the fact that the other person is facing a point of no return, they will face (subjectively to themselves) a real situation (they succumb to their fate in a manner).

Ἀψευδὴ= (Ancient Greek: Ἀψευδὴς means 'truthful' or 'the shiner'[1])
was one of the 50 Nereids, sea-nymph daughters of the 'Old Man of the Sea' Nereus and the Oceanid Doris.[1]
[2] Her name means 'she who never lies', which like her sister Nemertes, inherited their father's quality of a god who tells the truth.[3]

I chose this to describe the fact that once being forced to face said situation (their skin being in the game) their instincts overrule their tendency to rationalize the optimal response (the lies we all tell each other).

Credit goes to wikipedia.org and whomever provided it with the information for the definitions and explanations.
I hope it helps you as much as it has helped me in the past few years.

Disclosure: I do not speak ancient Greek, and my understanding of it is limited. I presume the orthography, grammar, and syntax could be improved.

Comment: Not easy to pronounce, I **must** say...:)

Comment: I know, I'm struggling myself, perhaps one day a better word will present itself. I chose this one due to its poetical roots.

Comment: Also, I think it describes the redundancy of the lengths needed to be taken in order to make someone face their own hypocrisy, namely one-upping it, metahypocrisy?, hyporciseption??

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).